# Python3: access a dunder variable

Tags: python, oop

I know what Python dunder variables are, and I'm aware of name mangling.

But for some reason I can't access the dunder variable in the following code snippet:

```
    for node in ast.find_all((Call,)):
        # Check if the identifier match the extension name
        if node.node.identifier == 'myapp.ext.MyExtension':
            # I want to access node.__meta
            print("==> type(node) = %s" % type(nod))
            print("==> node.__dict__ = %s" % node.__dict__")
```

Which prints:

```
==> type(node) = <class 'jinja2.nodes.Call'>
==> node.__dict__ = {
        'kwargs': [],
        # ... a bunch of other attributes
        # The __meta attribute below is what I want to access
        '__meta': {'type': 'checkbox', 'value': Const(value='checked'), 'name': Const(value='agree'), 'class': Const(value='bold')}
    }
```

Since the `node` variable is an instance of the `Call` class, and I want to access its `__meta` attribute, according to name mangling, I'd have to do it like this `node._Call__meta`, but I'm getting an error:

```
`'Call' object has no attribute '_Call__meta'`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That `__meta` appears to be unmangled. Perhaps it's set from outside the class?

Comment: *Dunder* is a new term for me. I've always heard of double underscore (*dunder*) methods as *magic methods*. Searching SO, I see hundreds of "[python] dunder" hits and tens of thousands of "[python] magic" hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a slight misunderstanding about how name mangling and the `__dict__` interact. `__dict__` entries are *not* subject to name mangling - if you see the name `'__meta'` in the `__dict__`, then the attribute is literally named `__meta` (and not `_Call__meta`).

You can confirm this yourself with this little demonstration:

```
class Demo:
    __meta = 5

print('__meta' in vars(Demo))  # False
print('_Demo__meta' in vars(Demo))  # True
```

There are two ways to access this `__meta` attribute:

1. If your code isn't inside a class, you can use `node.__meta`. This won't work in a class because then `__meta` will get name-mangled.
2. Alternatively, you can grab the attribute directly from the `__dict__` with `node.__dict__['__meta']`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Aran-Fey! In my case, it was your second option that worked for me.